# Proxy exceptions not being picked up Win7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, proxy

I'm trying to bypass my proxy to view an image. If I switch off proxy I can view it, but with proxy on it fails to access. If the image is available at

> http://demo.mycompany.net/download/icons/image.png

I went into Internet properties, connections tab, LAN settings, Advanced and added **http://demo.mycompany.net** to the box. I still can't access said image though.

What have I done wrong?

Edit: ideally I'd like this exception to work across all browsers. I hope its not a browser independent setting.

Comment: There isn't enough information here really. When you say "my proxy", I assume that you mean a corporate one? Do you have permission to try to bypass it? What are the proxy rules - do you have proxy.pac file? Is demo.mycompany.net on the same network as your machine?

Comment: Yes I do mean a corporate one and we have permission to bypass it. Nope to the .pac file. Yeah that address is on the same network.

Comment: OK. Firstly, it is unlikely that your org. really wants to proxy internal servers. So they should be using a proxy.pac that excludes internal resources. Then you wouldn't need to be messing with this. Secondly, the override should look like: `localhost;127.0.0.1;*.local;nn.nn.nn.nn`. where nn.nn.nn.nn is the IP address of the server. demo.mycompany.net should also work but try the IP address. `ping demo.mycompany.net` should get you the address